# how to ovelap a image on other image by styling scss in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a design. In this design, one is overlapping on another image. I have created some code to try as given in the design. but it's not working for me. [Click here](https://ibb.co/QN4S8Ss) to find the design

Below is some line of code of components. that is tried by me

```
<div className="container">
  <Image className="container-img1" src={img1}/>
  <Image className="container-img2" src={img2}/>
</div>
```

below is a style in scss

```
.container{
  text-align: center;
  .container-img1{
     position: inherit;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     height: auto;
     border-radius: 50%;
     border: 3px solid grey;
     margin-right: -5rem;
  }
  .container-img1{
     position: inherit;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     height: auto;
     border-radius: 50%;
     border: 3px solid grey;
     margin-left: -5rem;
  }
}
```

[Click Here](https://ibb.co/xXYvg1L) to check what I have designed. but it's not looking as given in design.

How can I style the same as given in Design? And should be responsive also.

Comment: The image you are using looks like a transparent image and that's why the image on back is visible. You can also use `z-index` to change the stack order. Can you upload your working demo code in platform like `Codesandbox` so that we can debug?

Comment: @ashiish.me yeah that's correct but how can we remove the border when it's ovelap?

Comment: You don't have to remove the border, use a solid background image with no opacity and it will be hidden inside another image.

Comment: @ashiish.me Ok, So you mean the marked border will also gone? https://ibb.co/qg84HFh

Comment: No not the border on left that you have marked but the border on right will be hidden. Also, the demo image that you have attached on question has the border on left too.

Comment: @ashiish.me, no there is no border in image. Grey color border is not there? https://ibb.co/QN4S8Ss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230178/discussion-between-kwall-and-ashiish-me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the demo image you can eliminate the border with transparency for the `img2` that has higher stack order in DOM.

```css
.container-img1 {
  position: inherit;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 7rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  /* Reduce the margin so that the border aligns properly */
  margin-right: -1.1rem;
}

.container-img2 {
  position: inherit;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 7rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  /* Reduce the margin so that the border aligns properly */
  margin-left: -1.1rem;
  /* make it transparent */
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

To make it responsive, the image width seems very small but you need to adjust the width & margin according to the device size using media query.